# Kendo UI & Vue.js combination does not work and throws error

Tags: kendo-ui, vue.js, telerik

I have just begun application development with Kendo UI & Vue.js. I have developed Kendo UI applications earlier but without Vue.js. As I started putting the basic code in place to test how Vue.js would work for me, I saw that Kendo UI fails when the Vue object is initialized and takes over. Kendo.all.min.js throws an error - i is undefined and this renders all the UI useless. The UI then takes no clicks, no inputs. To demonstrate I have created a DOJO here - http://dojo.telerik.com/oDAsE. When the Vue code is commented, the dropdowns in the toolbars work. When you uncomment the Vue code, the toolbar stops responding and console shows the exception - i is undefined when you perform some actions on the toolbar (try clicking the dropdown). I could not post this on telerik forums as my subscription period has expired :(. Appreciate your help !!

Comment: if i move the vue code block before the kendo-toolbar init - it works. but that cannot be a solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems like in your case the Vue object initialization is updating the dom in a way that breaks the logic that is expected in Kendo Toolbar. In such scenarios I would recommend using the official [Kendo-Vue.js integration](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/toolbar/vue) that designed and tested against such possible gliches.

Comment: sure, will test it with that and reply with my findings.